# For a given graph G = (V,E) how can you sort its adjacency list representation in O(E+V) time?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, graph

Because we know that the integers representing a vertex can take values in `[0,...,|V|-1]` range, we can use counting sort in order to sort each entry of the adjacency list in `O(V)` time.

Since we have `V` lists to sort, that would give us a `O(V^2)` time algorithm. I don't see how we can transform this into an `O(V+E)` time algorithm...

Comment: Did you read somewhere that it is possible?

Comment: yes

http://www2.cs.uni-paderborn.de/cs/ag-madh/vorl/GraphAlgorithmsI02/l1.pdf

page 22, but I don't get the idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you need to sort `E` elements in total - the number of edges. Thus your estimation of `O(V^2)` is not quite correct. You sort each of the adjacency lists in linear time with respect to **the number of edges it contains**. And as in total you will have E edges, the complexity of sorting all lists will be `O(E)`. Of course as you have `V` lists, you can't get lower than `O(V)` and thus the estimation `O(V +E)`.

Comment: An edge can be in at most two adjacency lists, assuming that your graph is not directed. If the graph is directed, an edge will be in exactly one adjacency list

Comment: but you are using counting sort, so for each index of your adjacency list, you will have to run through the bucket array which is of size |V| exactly once... I don't see how you can avoid doing that.

Comment: @jsguy you can re-use the same array for all the sorts. Also you can have an additional container of linear size where you store which are the buckets you've modified and you can only clear them after each sort. Alternatively you can do one more iteration over the input array and use it instead of this additional container, clearing only buckets that correspond to its elements

Comment: Another way of doing this would probably be the following:

Initiallize an array `A` of size `|V|`, so the positions range from `1....|V|`

A[u] will store all edges (v,u) that appear in your input adjacency list.

You can update A by just reading your input adjacency list.

Then in the end you have a for loop for the positions in A, and for every A[i] you read the edges (v,u) and append the edge (u,v) to the output adjacency list. This is quite similar to counting sort, but I feel like it's not the same thing, but definitely has the same complexity as the counting sort approach.